# Are nested inline functions allowed (by the standard) in C programming language?

Tags: c, inline, clion

I just learned that inline functions can be defined in another function's body as well.

I'm using the mpicc compiler and the following code compiles successfully without warnings and errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    inline int inlinetest(int x) {
        return x * 4;
    }

    printf("%d\n", inlinetest(8));
    return 0;
}
```

However, CLion shows the following errors within the file:

A the `{` bracket of `inlinetest`: Function definition is not allowed here

Where I try to call `inlinetest`: Implicit declaration of function 'inlinetest' is invalid in C99

I tried setting the `CMAKE_C_STANDARD` and `C_STANDARD` to 11, but this doesn't make a difference.

Is there a way to configure CMake or CLion itself, such that it doesn't detect this "error"?

Comment: Why are you writing "error"? It is an error. Your sentence `I just learned that inline functions can be defined in another function's body as well.` is wrong. Functions in functions are not allowed. The keyword `inline` means that the function will be put instead of the function call, it makes `8*4` instead of `inlinetest(8)`. It does not allow a function definition inside of a function.

Comment: @mch But if it's an error: Why doesn't the compiler complain then? I know, what ``inline`` does and was amazed of why this works anyway...

Comment: You cannot define a function within another function in standard C.

You can declare a function inside of a function, but it's not a nested function.

gcc has a language extension that allows nested functions.[see_here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) They are nonstandard, and as such are entirely compiler-dependent.

Comment: @Adam: “Standard C” includes both *strictly conforming programs*, which may not have nested function definitions, and *conforming programs*, which may.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: thank you, i didnt knew that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm sure you're aware, your `mpicc` compiler is a wrapper for a real
compiler, which is your case apparently is `gcc`.

In your example you have defined `inlinetest` as a *nested function* within `main`.

Nested functions are [a language extension in GNU C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)
They are not supported by Standard C.

`gcc` will compile your program clean with default options:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    inline int inlinetest(int x) {
        return x * 4;
    }

    printf("%d\n", inlinetest(8));
    return 0;
}
$ gcc main.c
$ ./a.out
32
```

but `gcc` will complain if you direct it to enforce any C standard from the oldest:

```
$ gcc -std=c89 -pedantic main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:5: error: ‘inline’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    4 |     inline int inlinetest(int x) {
      |     ^~~~~~
main.c:4:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:4:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
    4 |     inline int inlinetest(int x) {
      |           ^~~~
      |           ;
```

to the latest:

```
$ gcc -std=c18 -pedantic main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:5: warning: ISO C forbids nested functions [-Wpedantic]
    4 |     inline int inlinetest(int x) {
      |     ^~~~~~
```

I'm not familiar with CLion, but IDEs that boast on-the-fly code analysis always
harbour the potential nuisance that the on-the-fly analyser will disagree
with the compiler on some points. The IDE will probably give you some way to review the analyser's rules catalog and tweak it to silence nuisance diagnostics.
But I would not hope you can get CLion to recognize GNU C nested functions: they
are arcane.

And for that reason I suggest that you don't pick this fight. You surely
haven't found a compelling reason to make you code rely on support for GNU C nested functions,
so just don't bother with them.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your answer! My example in the question is just a minimal example of what I mean. The context, in which I found out about this, was code my professor gave out for us students. In that code, he used many nested functions, most of them referencing variables from the function it was defined in. I just wanted to make sure, if this is standard in C. Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

The C standard allows nested function definitions in the sense that it allows C implementations to support such definitions as an extension to the core language: a *conforming program* may have nested function definitions but can only be used with compilers that support them.

The C language does not allow nested function definitions in the sense that they are defined as part of the core language: a *strictly conforming program* does not have nested function definitions.

With a compiler not designed to support nested function definitions, you cannot expect a switch can be easily provided to “ignore” the errors resulting from nested function definitions. Supporting nested function definitions requires deliberate design and engineering in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard does not support nested function definitions. Some compilers allow them as an extension, notably `gcc`. Note however that since your nested function does not refer to local variables in the outer function, you can just move its definition outside the body of the outer function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

inline int inlinetest(int x) {
    return x * 4;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", inlinetest(8));
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that `inline` may be ignored by the compiler, and that some modern compilers will inline functions based on actual usage even without the `inline` keyword.